# new file default execution permission?

Tags: permissions, filesystem, umask

I can't figure out why I don't have execution permissions on files I create by default.
I don't think I messed with any Ubuntu permissions, it's pretty default stuff.

When doing some research I found out about a thing called umask, running `umask` returns `0002` I don't think that's the problem. I've tried creating files in a bunch of different folders, they all look like `-rw-rw-r--`.

```
farzher@farzher-laptop ~ $ touch pants.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 farzher farzher     0 Jul 24 21:58 pants.txt
```

I know how to execute it `chmod 755 pants.txt` but I want execute by default. If I'm missing any important information just comment and ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the applications used to create those files chose to not give them execution permissions in the first place. If you want to change this then you will need to modify the applications.

Comment: I've used multiple applications, they all look the same; and the example I showed I'm using `touch` shouldn't that have execute on user?

Comment: Only if they choose to. **Which they don't.**

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. Ty, you saved me a lot of searching.