# How to Create Text Files with user execution bit set automatically

Tags: permissions, files, umask

The closest I got was umask to change the default permissions set for files/folders. However, umask doesn't seem to allow enabling the `x` bit for files:

The base permissions for directories are `0777 (rwxrwxrwx)` and for files they are `0666 (rw-rw-rw-)`. [Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/umask)

I also saw this [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324180/new-file-default-execution-permission) which makes sense, but still, umask clearly has an involvement in the issue, not just touch's code, because when I change umask, touch's results are affected).

Is there any way to create files with the execution bit set, at least for the user section (ideally `-rwx-r-x-r-x = 755`)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to create files with the execution bit set, at least
>   for the user section (ideally -rwx-r-x-r-x = 755)

Yes.

`setfacl`command will do what you want. See `man setfacl` for a complete manual.

> ```
> sudo setfacl -Rdm g:groupnamehere:rwx /base/path/members/
> sudo setfacl -Rm g:groupnamehere:rwx /base/path/members/
> ```
>
> **R** is recursive, which means everything under that directory will have
>   the rule applied to it. **d** is default, which means for all future items
>   created under that directory, have these rules apply by default. **m** is
>   needed to add/modify rules.
>
> The first command, is for new items (hence the d), the second command,
>   is for old/existing items under the folder. Hope this helps someone
>   out as this stuff is a bit complicated and not very intuitive.

[source](https://serverfault.com/a/445096)

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong here, but still, any new files being created with `touch` or `gedit` have none of the executable bits set.

Comment: does it help to say that `/etc/login.defs` has `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes`

Comment: Try to set the `acl` option in /etc/fstab at the filesystem.